# The entity type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a key to be defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I have a ASP.NET5 MVC application using EF7. It works all fine so far and i'm able to add migrations and persist data in the database.
Now after adding Identity to my data layer project I get this error when trying to add a new migration:

> The entity type
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserLogin'
>   requires a key to be defined

My context is derived from IdentityDbContext:

```
public class ASSWebApiContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
```

the AppUser class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;

namespace ASS.DomainDataModel.Models
{
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string AppUserId { get; set; }
        public DateTime FirstFlight { get; set; }
    }
}
```

project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "ASS.DomainDataModel Class Library",
  "authors": [ "xxxx" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
      }
    }
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "ASS.DomainClasses": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Relational": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "System.Linq.Expressions": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

    "commands": {
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  }
}
```

All I have done here is to load the relevant new package:
"Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final", added the AppUser class - nothing else. I had a similar project using beta-8 using the exact same pattern where it worked without problems. Are there any relevant changes between beta-8 and rc-1?

thanks!

Below is part of the ASSWebApiContext. There's a modelBuilder.Entity for most of the entities that have a DbSet.  So the file goes on for quite a while...

```
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using ASS.DomainClasses.Entities;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions;
using System.Linq;
using ASS.DomainClasses.Interfaces;
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace ASS.DomainDataModel.Models
{
    public class ASSWebApiContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    {
        public IConfigurationBuilder Config { get; set; }
        public IConfigurationRoot _Configuration { get; private set; }

        public ASSWebApiContext(IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();

            Config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
                .AddJsonFile("config.json");

            _Configuration = Config.Build();

        }

        public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AddressType> AddressTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Aircraft> Aircrafts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AircraftModel> AircraftModels { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AircraftOwner> AircraftOwners { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AircraftOwnerType> AircraftOwnerTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GPEncodingType> GPEncodingTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LocationPoint> LocationPoints { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Manufacturer> Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Pilot> Pilots { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ServiceProvider> ServiceProviders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Trip> Trips { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Stop> Stops { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Track> Tracks { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {


            modelBuilder.Entity<AddressType>(
                e =>
                {
                    e.Property(n => n.AddressTypeId).IsRequired().UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
                    e.Property(n => n.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(15);
                    e.Ignore(n => n.IsDirty);
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Address>(
                e =>
                {
                    e.Property(n => n.AddressId).IsRequired().UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
                    e.Property(n => n.AddressTypeId).IsRequired();
                    e.Property(i => i.CountryId).HasMaxLength(2);
                    e.Property(i => i.AddrLine1).HasMaxLength(256);
                    e.Property(i => i.AddrLine2).HasMaxLength(256);
                    e.Property(i => i.AddrLine3).HasMaxLength(256);
                    e.Property(i => i.Postcode).HasMaxLength(50);
                    e.Ignore(n => n.IsDirty);
                });
...
```

Comment: Can we see the definition for IdentityUserLogin?

Comment: It's a system Type...?

Comment: Yes, but you must have used it somewhere or inherited from it?  You have posted `IdentityUser`, but not where you have used `IdentityUserLogin`

Comment: No, Not yet. Just tried to add Identity and a Migration to add the relevant tables. I did the same in the Beta 8 Project without that Problem.

Comment: Actually scratch that, it's a bit more complicated than just adding the key definition into IdentityUser, you have to define all the other types if you do what I previously suggested

Comment: can you show definition of `ASSWebApiContext` , especially `onModelCreating` method if you are overriding it?

Comment: I wonder if anything on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531201/entitytype-identityuserlogin-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entit) helps?

Comment: @Coulton - thanks for the link but It doesn't seem to work for me. I do have only one dbcontext and re the comment at the very end of the post, I have not changed the pk for the user. I actually only created the AppUserId after I got the 'requires a key to be defined' error. And it doesn't change if i remove my AppUserId from the AppUser class.

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid I have just removed all content from the onModelCreating method as there's a lot. It does work fine when i remove the Identity stuff from the project. But once it's being added it doesn't matter if I keep my overrides in there or not by the looks of it.

I'll add it to the original post.

Comment: I have 3 projects in total. 1. MVC and Web Api, one data layer (db context and migrations) and another which contains the entities. The AppUser class was created in the data layer project. Not sure if that might cause the problem but that's the biggest difference between this project and the other one where i used the same technique using beta-8. That beta-8 solution actually had only 1 project holding all of the above described components.

Comment: try adding `base.onModelCreating(modelBuilder)` in your override and it should be the first statement of overridden method. See if that helps?

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid That did it! thanks a lot!!! How do I set your comment to become the answer to my question? Also, is there a source where I can read-up on what happened there? I'm not quite sure I understand why adding that statement fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Basically the keys of Identity tables are mapped in `OnModelCreating` method of `IdentityDbContext` and if this method is not called, you will end up getting the error that you got. This method is not called if you derive from `IdentityDbContext` and provide your own definition of `OnModelCreating` as you did in your code. With this setup you have to explicitly call the `OnModelCreating` method of `IdentityDbContext` using `base.OnModelCreating` statement.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531201/entitytype-identityuserlogin-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entit) also discusses the option I posted here

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked on .NET 5, and I came across the same issue. In my case, I have derived classes for `ApplicationUser`, `ApplicationRole`, and `ApplicationUserRole` that derive from `IdentityUser`, `IdentityRole` and `IdentityUserRole`.

`ApplicationUserRole` has a complex key that is a combination of UserId, and RoleId, and defined the same in the OnModelCreating method.

Down the line while seeding the data, I was referring to `IdentityUserRole` instead of `ApplicationUserRole` while adding a role to a user. That caused the same problem. After some trouble, I had realized what was going wrong. I just changed it to `ApplicationUserRole`.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps anyone I had this issue and was going crazy as I was already overriding OnModelCreating.

It turns out that when overriding IIdentityUser I was using the wrong namespace that intellisense suggested.

I was using:

> Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework

And should have been using

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

Answer (score 0):

In dotnet core 7 I added [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key] for primary keys available on all models. Problem solved.

Comment: Microsoft has not added `[Key]` to `IdentityUserLogin<string>`.  How did you add it to the model?

Comment: Be aware of the following issue: `The entity type 'SomeEntity' has multiple properties with the [Key] attribute. Composite primary keys can only be set using 'HasKey' in 'OnModelCreating'`  So, I one cannot place `[Key]` attribute on `IdentityUserLogin<string>`,