# Entity framework code first approach getting "primary key required" error for a table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, identityserver4

I am trying to use **Code First** approach. In the table **AspNetUserLogins**, I've composite primary key of **LoginProvider** and **ProviderKey**. Now I am getting following error for this table:

> "InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'AspNetUserLogins'
>   requires a primary key to be defined."

Also, DB is not getting created.

[image]

**My Context class:**

```
    public partial class MyTestDB_devContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
       public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoleClaims> AspNetRoleClaims { get; set; }
       public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
       public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaims> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
       public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogins> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
       public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserRoles> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
       public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserTokens> AspNetUserTokens { get; set; }
       public virtual DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }

       protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
       {
         optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=MyTestDB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
       }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       { modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserLogin<string>", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<string>("LoginProvider");        
                    b.Property<string>("ProviderKey");        
                    b.Property<string>("ProviderDisplayName");        
                    b.Property<string>("UserId")
                        .IsRequired();        
                    b.HasKey("LoginProvider", "ProviderKey");        
                    b.HasIndex("UserId");        
                    b.ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");
                });
           modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityRole", b =>
              {
                   ...        
                    b.ToTable("AspNetRoles");
                });

                modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityRoleClaim<string>", b =>
                {
                   ...        
                    b.ToTable("AspNetRoleClaims");
                });

                modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserClaim<string>", b =>
                {
                    ...        
                    b.ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");
                });   
                modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserRole<string>", b =>
                {
                    ...        
                    b.ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
                });

                modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserToken<string>", b =>
                {
                    ...        
                    b.ToTable("AspNetUserTokens");
                });

                modelBuilder.Entity<DataModel.DBModels.ApplicationUser>( b =>
                {
                    ...          
                    b.ToTable("AspNetUsers");
                }); 
                      modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityRoleClaim<string>", b =>
                {                        b.HasOne("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityRole")
                        .WithMany("Claims")
                        .HasForeignKey("RoleId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
                });

                modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserClaim<string>", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("DataModel.DBModels.ApplicationUser")
                        .WithMany("Claims")
                        .HasForeignKey("UserId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
                });

                modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserLogin<string>", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("DataModel.DBModels.ApplicationUser")
                        .WithMany("Logins")
                        .HasForeignKey("UserId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
                });

                modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserRole<string>", b =>
                {                        b.HasOne("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityRole")
                        .WithMany("Users")
                        .HasForeignKey("RoleId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

                    b.HasOne("DataModel.DBModels.ApplicationUser")
                        .WithMany("Roles")
                        .HasForeignKey("UserId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
                });
            }
        }
```

I added HasKey option for `'AspNetUserLogins'` but still I am getting same error.

Comment: So you are posting the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43238563/861716) under another account? Please look at my comment there.

Comment: Yeah what are you doing? why are you creating tables that already exist in certain assemblies

Comment: This question has been asked and answered a number of times ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34000091/the-entity-type-microsoft-aspnet-identity-entityframework-identityuserloginstr

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with this code:

```
public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoleClaims> AspNetRoleClaims { get; set; }
```

The type argument of DbSet is the same as the DbSet variable itself.
It should look something like this:

```
public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoleClaim> AspNetRoleClaims { get; set; }
```

Because `AspNetRoleClaims` is a table, with records of type `AspNetRoleClaim`