# EF Core: error when attempting to add table to ApplicationDbContext

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I have a .NET 6 / EF Core 6 DB-first application with the standard `ApplicationDbContext` inherited from `IdentityContext`. I would like to extend this by adding a table from the whole database (included in my other 'business' `DbContext`).

However, adding just one table as so:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<business_units> business_units { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
       base.OnModelCreating(builder);

       builder.Entity<business_units>().ToTable("business_units"); //New table
    }
}
```

yields an error upon running the following in my AuthManager:

```
var u =_context.Users.Where(x => x.UserName.ToUpper() == email.ToUpper()).First();
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'AspNetUserLogins' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types,

`_context` is of type `ApplicationDbContext`.

The code runs fine without me attempting to add this table and I can't see how I'm somehow invalidating the primary key requirement on a different Identity table by adding this seemingly unconnected table.

I'd wondered if it was an issue with a table being in more than one context?

Update:

It appears that it has something to do with having foreign keys in the Identity tables (ie I can add a table that is not related to the Identity tables this way).  So does this mean I need to bring the Identity tables into the context (which feels like duplication given their derived objects such as 'User' are already therein)?  It also doesn't seem like that's what the error is telling me - my added table has no relationships with AspNewUserLogins.

Comment: I agree that this is weird. I found you would get this issue if you wouldn't call `base.OnModelCreating(builder);` in the `ApplicationDbContext.OnModelCreating`. But you do. Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70443975) help? It mentions usings/namespaces.

Comment: I think in that question the usings were .net framework instead of .net Core - I'm referencing AspNetCore assemblies.

Comment: @RichFreeman, Have you ever override the AspNetUserLogins model, such as add custom property? I create a new Asp.net core sample, and test your code, everything works well, check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPr5t.gif). The AspNetUsersLogins is the standard class that comes with Identity, and it has 2 primary keys, which are LoginProvider and ProviderKey. So, if you doesn't  change them, by default and use your code, it will not show this error. You can create a new application to verify it. Or, you can create a simple sample to reproduce the problem and share it via github.

Comment: Like Zhi Lv says: what you show should work. The bug is in what you don't show. If you don't give a [mcve] we cannot help you. We're not clairvoyant.