# The type or namespace name 'User' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In my attempt to fix a "no key defined error" that I found a fix for here (Option 2 answer):

[EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531201/entitytype-identityuserlogin-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entit)

I found myself with the below error when inheriting the IdentityDbContext class.  All of the parameters are showing up as not found.  I included my "using" list to see if perhaps I am missing one that I am not aware of.  I am confused as I think the "using" I need is already being used.  Help?

```
using IdentitySample.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace FlavorPing.Models
{
    public class FlavorPingContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
    {

        public FlavorPingContext() : base("name=FlavorPingContext")
        {
        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FlavorPing.Models.Merchant> Merchants { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FlavorPing.Models.MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FlavorPing.Models.MerchantDetails> MerchantDetails { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FlavorPing.Models.Follower> Followers { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FlavorPing.Models.FollowerMenuItemMerchant> FollowerMenuItemMerchants { get; set; }

        public DbSet<UserLogin> UserLogins { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }


         protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder) {
        // Primary keys
        builder.Entity<Follower>().HasKey(q => q.FollowerID);
        builder.Entity<MenuItem>().HasKey(q => q.MenuItemID);
        builder.Entity<Merchant>().HasKey(q => q.MerchantID);
        builder.Entity<FollowerMenuItemMerchant>().HasKey(q => 
            new { 
                q.FollowerID, q.MenuItemID, q.MerchantID
            });

        // Relationships
        builder.Entity<FollowerMenuItemMerchant>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.Follower)
            .WithMany(t => t.FollowerMenuItemMerchants)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.FollowerID);

        builder.Entity<FollowerMenuItemMerchant>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.MenuItem)
            .WithMany(t => t.FollowerMenuItemMerchants)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.MenuItemID);

        builder.Entity<FollowerMenuItemMerchant>()
        .HasRequired(t => t.Merchant)
        .WithMany(t => t.FollowerMenuItemMerchants)
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.MerchantID);


        builder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        builder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        // Configure Asp Net Identity Tables
        builder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");
        builder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.PasswordHash).HasMaxLength(500);
        builder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Stamp).HasMaxLength(500);
        builder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.PhoneNumber).HasMaxLength(50);

        builder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("Role");
        builder.Entity<UserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
        builder.Entity<UserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        builder.Entity<UserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
        builder.Entity<UserClaim>().Property(u => u.ClaimType).HasMaxLength(150);
        builder.Entity<UserClaim>().Property(u => u.ClaimValue).HasMaxLength(500);
    }


    }
}
```

Comment: Do you actually have a class called User of type IdentityUser?

Comment: Yes that is part of the Identity Framework.

http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear, I was wondering if you were doing a custom implementation of user or not.  If not I'm thinking you do not need the builder code block for Entity<User>, try commenting that out.

Comment: Also, I think it is ApplicationUser not User...hard to tell without seeing more of your implementation though

Comment: Oh ok, I get where you are going now.  I will work on that.

Comment: But yes I am not custom implementing user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98022/discussion-between-jp-hochbaum-and-lazy-coder).