# EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting these errors when trying to create a merchant.

```
FlavorPing.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

FlavorPing.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

UserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'UserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.

UserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'UserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined."
```

Here is my merchant model:

```
namespace FlavorPing.Models
{
    public class Merchant
    {
        //Meant to inherit identity.
        //[ForeignKey("ApplicationUserId")]
        public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
        public virtual List<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }


        [Key]
        public int MerchantID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Business Name")]
        public string MerchantName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string email { get; set; }

        //need to create formatting here.
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Web Site Link")]
        public string website { get; set; }

        //public int MenuItemID { get; set; }


        public virtual List<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }

        public virtual MerchantDetails MerchantDetails { get; set; }

        public ICollection<FollowerMenuItemMerchant> FollowerMenuItemMerchants { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the create controller for merchant, which is where I am getting the error:

```
// POST: Merchants/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "MerchantID,MerchantName,email,website")] Merchant merchant)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        merchant.ApplicationUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        db.Merchants.Add(merchant);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(merchant);
}
```

Here is my DBContext:

```
namespace FlavorPing.Models
{
    public class FlavorPingContext : IdentityDbContext
    {

        public FlavorPingContext()
            : base("name=FlavorPingContext")
        {
        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FlavorPing.Models.Merchant> Merchants { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FlavorPing.Models.MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FlavorPing.Models.MerchantDetails> MerchantDetails { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FlavorPing.Models.Follower> Followers { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<FlavorPing.Models.FollowerMenuItemMerchant> FollowerMenuItemMerchants { get; set; }

        public DbSet<IdentityUserLogin> UserLogins { get; set; }
        public DbSet<IdentityUserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }
        public DbSet<IdentityUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
        {
            // Primary keys
            builder.Entity<Follower>().HasKey(q => q.FollowerID);
            builder.Entity<MenuItem>().HasKey(q => q.MenuItemID);
            builder.Entity<Merchant>().HasKey(q => q.MerchantID);
            builder.Entity<FollowerMenuItemMerchant>().HasKey(q =>
                new
                {
                    q.FollowerID,
                    q.MenuItemID,
                    q.MerchantID
                });

            // Relationships
            builder.Entity<FollowerMenuItemMerchant>()
                .HasRequired(t => t.Follower)
                .WithMany(t => t.FollowerMenuItemMerchants)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.FollowerID);

            builder.Entity<FollowerMenuItemMerchant>()
                .HasRequired(t => t.MenuItem)
                .WithMany(t => t.FollowerMenuItemMerchants)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.MenuItemID);

            builder.Entity<FollowerMenuItemMerchant>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.Merchant)
            .WithMany(t => t.FollowerMenuItemMerchants)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.MerchantID);


            builder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            builder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();


        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to follow the example (option2) in this link:  [EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531201/entitytype-identityuserlogin-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entit)

I am trying Option 2 because I want to avoid having two DB's.  But I am new to managing a DB so if you think I should do Option 3 please advise as to why, or if you see why I am getting this error please tell me why.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you defined PK's for the tables that you mentioned?

Comment: Yes for example, under Follower:

[Key]
        public int FollowerID { get; set; }

Comment: Option 2 is the easiest option. Go for it.

Answer (score 19):

Ok I fixed my issue by adding this into my DBContext class.

```
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
    builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
```

Comment: mine was working fine and then I created a ADO. NET EF model and included the AspNetTables. I then got rid of the context VS created and also the AspNetTable Classes , but kept my original context which had no code for AspNetUsers etc..- and then this garbage error.! MS is sticking the info somewhere..I will try your solution now - because I have no choice but to edit my code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you get the errors because your foreign key attributes aren't in the correct spot (and have the wrong name), instead of this:

```
public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
public virtual List<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

You need to do this:

```
[ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

public virtual List<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

The ID is the foreign key to the virtual entity, not the other way around.

Comment: Wow that was an error I completely overlooked, thanks!

Comment: Actually, either way will work, but you have to reference the right property. In the OP's code, it would need to be `[ForeignKey("ApplicationUserId")]`, implying that the navigation property has `ApplicationUserId` as it's foreign key.

Comment: I am not entirely sure it fixed the problem, as I am now getting other errors from making that correction, but I do know both comments above are correct.

Comment: Okay I fixed my other errors and still getting same error now.