# ApplicationUser as lazyloading/foreign key in another code first entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-mvc-5

The error in package manager console :

> EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for
>   this EntityType.
>  EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key
>   defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>  'IdentityUserLogins'
>   is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
>   'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no
>   keys defined.

Code I am using:

```
public string UserId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("UserId")] 
public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

In `OnmodelCreating` I have:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
}
```

I also checked the database, and the Identity tables have been created and have primary keys also.

Comment: I think you're missing the primary key of the table. Try to add [Key] to your primary property in model.

Comment: What's the full model here?  And why are you re-defining the keys for `IdentityUserLogin` and the other classes?  Shouldn't you have a `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)` call at the end of your override (presuming that this is your context, and you've inherited from `IdentityDbContext`)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531201/entitytype-identityuserlogin-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entit