# How to create a migration in ASP.Net MVC 5 application after making changes to the identity model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am building an application in c# using ASP.NET MVC 5/Entity 6 frameworks with code first approach. I changed the `Id` attribute in Identity 2 from `string` to `integer` using the [documentation](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity).

Then I create the migration using the following command

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
```

The migration failed to add due to the following errors

```
DbContexts.CustomUserLogin: : EntityType 'CustomUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
DbContexts.CustomUserRole: : EntityType 'CustomUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
CustomUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'CustomUserLogins' is based on type 'CustomUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
CustomUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'CustomUserRoles' is based on type 'CustomUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

I made some changes to the `ApplicationUser` class by adding more Foreign Keys and some relations like so

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Proj1.Areas.Base.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Proj1.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim> 
    {
        [ForeignKey("Role")]
        public int RoleId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Client")]
        public int CurrentClientId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Campaign")]
        public int? CurrentCampaignId { get; set; }

        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

        public virtual Campaign Campaign { get; set; }

        public virtual List<UserToPrivilege> UserToPrivileges { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

    }

    public class CustomUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
    public class CustomUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
    public class CustomUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }

    public class CustomRole : IdentityRole<int, CustomUserRole>
    {
        public CustomRole() { }
        public CustomRole(string name) { Name = name; }
    }

    public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int,
        CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
    {
        public CustomUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }
    }

    public class CustomRoleStore : RoleStore<CustomRole, int, CustomUserRole>
    {
        public CustomRoleStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }
    } 
}
```

What is the issue here? How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you post the code of the classes which are causing the error ?

Comment: I update my question

Comment: I tried this for one project, then realized it wasn't worth the effort to change the ids from string to int.

Comment: You're missing some important information. So you tried to generate the migration, it failed with the error you posted. You made changes to the `ApplicationUser` and then what? Where should be any issue? Are you trying to generate the migration again? Did it fail again? What errors did you get?

Comment: After changing the Identity attribute from string to int like the doc. I added the attributes to the `ApplicationUser` just like my code above. Then I tried to Add-Migration and that is when I got the error. So the migration is not generating do the error I stated in my questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531201/entitytype-identityuserlogin-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entit)