# ASP.NET Identity 2.0 DB First Approach: Adding new Columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2, db-first

I am trying to use ASP.NET Identity 2.0 with existing database.
I have created an MVC project (which uses Individual Account Authentication), then I registered  for a use  in order to create the DB.

Then:

1. I created scripts for the necessary tables and added them to my own DB
2. I added ADO.NET Entity Data Model (database first) which include my tables plus identity tables.
3. I ran the application and registered for a user, everything is going fine.

Now, I need to add a relation to `AspNetUser` table.

1. I added the Column LocationId with the relationship in DB.
2. I Added the following to the Application User Class:

   ```
   public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
   ```
3. Then, I updated my Model and run the application, when I tried to register for new user, I got the following error:

   > AspNet UserLogin: EntityType: EntitySet 'AspNetUserLogins' is based on type 'AspNet UserLogin' that has no keys defined.

How is it possible to continue using DB First Approach in this scenario?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28531201/861716

Comment: no it is not, I have not added any code for seed or custom mappings.

Comment: I just  added the identity tables to my custom DB, then added the model using DB First. I also have two connection strings pointing to the same DB. One for Identity and the other for the Database First Model.

Comment: The `Seed` method is irrelevant here. Did you understand the answer? I think your issue is explained right at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity uses Code First approach for making Identity System make customization as more as possible and you are using DB first approach for your common data access. So there are 2 contexts, one is for your data and other is for you Identity. You need to write **Identity classes** and make a code first migration of Identity context class by typing in the Package Manager Console as:

`Enable-Migrations -ContextNameType [Your_Identity_Context]

This will enable code first migrations just for your Identity context type. If you want to add region property in your user table, then in 'ApplicationUser' (or any class derived from IdentityUser) add the required region property and then apply the migrations to update the user table in the database.

Generating SQL script and applying to the database is not a good approach.

Comment: ok that worked. But, how i can rename the tables. Fluent Api is not working in my case.