# The entity type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a key to be defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

All was working fine until I introduced Identity.

I changed my context class to be:

```
public partial class VisualJobsDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    private IConfigurationRoot _config;

    public VisualJobsDbContext() { }

    public VisualJobsDbContext(IConfigurationRoot config, DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
        _config = config;
    }...
```

and I have a Generic repository that is declared in the form:

```
public abstract class GenericRepository<C,T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class where C : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, new() 
{
    private C _entities = new C();
    private VisualJobsDbContext context;
    private DbSet<T> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(VisualJobsDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }....
```

The Error occurs on the

> this.dbSet = context.Set<>();

the first time it gets hit. My OnModelCreating method does get called. The page I'm trying to get to from my MVC app does not require a login as it is a general page, but there will be areas that will require a login. However, I dont get as far as my controller Constructor method before it errors. To Register the service I have:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<VisualJobsDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

and I can step this ok.

any ideas what I'm missing? I have looked at this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531201/entitytype-identityuserlogin-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entit) and others, but it doesn't really help

Comment: Is the context being passed in to the ctor null? That would cause the behavior.

Comment: HI @ShawnWildermuth thanks for taking a look. Yes, my context is populated. if I do `typeof(T)` in the immediate window I can see that it's set to an 'Agent' object. in the Context I can see an Agent object as well. The Agent object along with all my other application objects have no reference to Application User. Do I need all my model object to inherit from this?

Comment: No it's not that. I set my agent object to inherit from Application user, but it still failed on this object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my OnModelCreating Method. I needed to place `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` as my first line of code.