# Many to Many relationship in Asp.Net MVC 5 with Identity table and Custom table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to make a relationship between the Users from the table generated by Asp.Net Identity with my own table. The relationship must be many to many, since many Users can work on the same Task (which is my table), and same time an User can work on multiple Tasks.

```
public class Task
{      
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string UserID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int TaskID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks{ get; set; }

    // rest of the code
}
```

I try it this way but I get an error during migration (or run time)

"One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:"
[image]

Please help me solve this problem and archive what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this:

1. ```
   public class Projects
   {
       public Projects()
       {
           ApplicationUser = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
       }
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set;     }
   }
   ```
2. Application User

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ApplicationUser()
        {
            Projects = new HashSet<Projects>();
        }
        public async Task GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }        
        public virtual ICollection <Projects > Projects { get; set; }
    }
```

3. Application Context :

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }
        public virtual DbSet<Projects> Projects { get; set; }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

now when I run this Mvc app and register, the db tables I get is like the following:

[image: From MSSQL]

and the correct schema:

[image]

The things to be questioned are a lot, from my point of view important is to determine  if you:
 - can/should you mix application context and your model context ?

Comment: I would prefer to keep my finger away from ApplicationDbContext

Comment: There is no way that you could use two different contexts with two dufferent tables and then query them in thr same linq query. You are restricted to use one context.

Comment: can you show those little changes ? hope it'll help others @Arianit

Comment: What changes @Arianit? It worked like that in my side.

Comment: is this correct `public virtual ICollection ApplicationUser { get; set;  }` ? @E.B

Comment: The problem is with the HashSets.It gives an error the way how you did it.

Comment: Ah, editor has removed the signs "<" & ">"  for collection

Comment: They are supposed to be in the way that a collection is written, like : 
public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser{get;set} , but in markdown the sign "<" has removed the rest of row... I'll edit it.

Comment: ok, it must be ok now. seriously replaced all of them with &lt; and &gt; , I'll find a smarter way for another time :D ...

Comment: I'm waiting for that smarter way

Answer (score 1):

You can try it as shown below using `Fluent API`.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
                .HasMany<ApplicationUser>(s => s.Users)
                .WithMany(c => c.Tasks)
                .Map(cs =>
                        {
                            cs.MapLeftKey("TaskRefId");
                            cs.MapRightKey("ApplicationUserRefId");
                            cs.ToTable("TaskApplicationUser");
                        });

}
```

**Update :** you can see this link too.

[**EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531201/entitytype-identityuserlogin-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entit)

Comment: this must be in my own context class not in the ApplicationDbContext class, right?

Comment: I didn't get you ?

Comment: there are 2 context classes, the one for the Identity that Asp.Net generates for me, called ApplicationDbContext. And the other context I made myself. So this code you wrote as answer must be in my Context class I guess. OR?

Comment: Yes,use your `context`.

Comment: did you try with the other `context` too ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124101/discussion-between-arianit-and-sampath).

Comment: please see the **Update**.

Answer (score 1):

Error text is not related to your many-to-many relationship. It tips that other built-in entities are not configured properly. So, It would be nice if you provided  full definition of your custom DbContext-class and how it is configured.

**UPDATE**

As i understood u are working with two different contexts. You must work with the same context, cause of u are extending IdentityContext, creating relationships and adding custom types. So problem then will be resolved itself. 
Hope, this will help.

Comment: but is it an acceptable practice to use the applicationdbcontext to work with the business logic?

Comment: Don't forget - it is just **DbContext**. ApplicationDbContext serves as repository itself. Every business logic needs a repository to persist or read data. Simple solutions can use ApplicationDbContext directly, in complex - u create ur own repositories. Also this is a bunch with authentication system.

Comment: but what bothers me is that in the future when I need to work with my custom db table, example reference it from an other table or to another table, I have to work with the ApplicationDbContext! This is a thing I kinda don't like. I want to use the ApplicationDbContext just for Identity