# IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a primary key to be defined error while adding migration

Tags: entity-framework

I am using 2 different Dbcontexts. i want to use 2 different databases users and mycontext. While doing that i am getting a error The entity type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserLogin' requires a primary key to be defined. I think there is something wrong with IdentityUser please suggest me where can i change my code so that i can add migration.

My Dbcontext class:

```
 class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.PostId, t.TagId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Post)
            .WithMany(p => p.PostTags)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.PostId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Tag)
            .WithMany(t => t.PostTags)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TagId);
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public AppUser User {get; set;}
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string TagId { get; set; }

    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class PostTag
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

and AppUser class:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
  //some other propeties
}
```

when I try to Add migration the following error occurs.

```
The entity type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a primary key to be defined.
```

give me solution to resolve the issue..

Comment: try this , I had same problem two dbcontext https://stackoverflow.com/a/40824620/7046796

Answer (score 268, accepted):

To reduce the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40824620/5757162) to a nutshell, try this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    ...
```

See Above link for more.

Comment: Had this problem with Core 3.0 extending ASPNetUsers but with a single DB.   added this line  to ApplicationDBContext.OnModelCreating and it worked a charm.

Comment: Does it matter where in the override of OnModelCreating you call base.OnModelCreating (i.e. does it need to be the first thing you call)?

Comment: I had to use "ModelBuilder" instead of "DbModelBuilder" for .NET Core

Comment: Great, I was supposed to use base because my CustomDbContext was inherited from IdentityDbContext

Answer (score 41):

This issue will start coming as soon as you wrote the following lines in DBContext without adding `'base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);'`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

}
```

Two solutions:

1) Don't override `OnModelCreating` in DbContext `Until it becomes necessary`

2) Override but call `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)`

Comment: ...I wish I could vote for an answer twice. Thank You!

Answer (score 8):

The problem is AppUser is inherited from IdentityUser and their primary keys are not mapped in the method OnModelCreating of dbcontext.

There is already a post available with resolution. Visit the below link

[EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531201/entitytype-identityuserlogin-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entit)

Hope this helps.