# ASP.NET Optional 1:1 relationship with ApplicationUser (Identity 2.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have a `Trainee` which must connect to an `ApplicationUser`. The `Trainee` model has fields that do not relate to the actual user account, but needs to get things like `FirstName`, `LastName` from `ApplicationUser` as **a user may not necessarily be a trainee**.

However, I get these errors, despite defining my foreign key for the user in `Trainee`:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> MyApp.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType
>   'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this
>   EntityType. MyApp.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType
>   'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this
>   EntityType...

...etc etc. Anyway, here's my current architecture:

The Trainee model:

```
public class Trainee
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string TraineeId { get; set; }

    // other fields, not relevant
    [ForeignKey("TraineeId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationUser and context:

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        // other arbitrary fields
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("SARSDbContext")
        {
        }
    }
```

Data context and model builder:

```
public class SARSDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Trainee> Trainees { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Trainee>()
                    .HasRequired(c => c.User);
    }
}
```

I looked [here](https://gilesey.wordpress.com/tag/entitytype-has-no-key-defined/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531201/entitytype-identityuserlogin-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entit/34786782) for info but I didn't find a solution.

Comment: I've just realised.. why do you have two DbContexts?

Comment: It's probably because that's what the tutorial said when I first learned mvc a couple years back. Never affected me until now :/