# How do I add a foreign key to aspnet user using EF code first?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

my code is:

```
public class UserGroupUser
{
    public int UserGroupUserId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [Key, ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

and when I try to create a controller I get this error:

> EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' had no key defined.Define the key for
>   this entity type.
>
> EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' had no key defined.Define the key for
>   this entity type.
>
> EntityType 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on 'IdentityUserLogin' that
>   has no key defined.
>
> EntityType: EnititySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on
>   'IdentityUserRole' that has no key defined.

but I can see the keys in my Database in SQL server management for all tables.
how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You have to specify primary keys for your EF entities by using `Id` property or `[Key]` attributes. Also it looks like you are using ASP.NET Identity, is it correct? If yes, pay attention to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531201/entitytype-identityuserlogin-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entit

Comment: Don't use `[Key]` on a nav property. Try `[Key, ForeignKey("ApplicationUser ")]` on the UserId property.

Answer (score 0):

Entity need a primary key. Change your other models accordingly.

```
public class UserGroupUser
{
    [Key]
    public int UserGroupUserId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thank you @Ppp for the answer. you are right. the [key] was missing in my code. but actually the problem was something else. although this problem is solved before in other posts, I will write it as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that EF doesn't recognize the keys in IdentityUserLogin, IdentityRole, IdentityUserRole tables(and I don't know the reason). so I had to tel it that those tables already have keys by overriding OnModelCreating method in my MainContext class(inherited from System.Data.Entity.DbContext):

```
public class MainContext : DbContext
{
    public MainContext() : base("MyDatabaseConnectionString") { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserGroupUser> UserGroupUsers { get; set; }

}
```

seems this method executes before generating the database.