# .Net Core API with EF Core Code First and IdentityUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an [existing application](https://www.bejebeje.com) that I am re-writing as .NET Core API with a ReactJS front-end. I am still in the API end, and I've run into a problem.

**CODE**

I have a `BbUser.cs` entity class with the following code:

```
public class BbUser : IdentityUser
{
  public int Points { get; set; } = 0;
  public string DisplayUsername { get; set; }
}
```

And I also have an `Artist.cs` entity class:

```
public class Artist
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  [Required]
  [MaxLength(50)]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  [MaxLength(50)]
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  [MaxLength(100)]
  public string UrlFriendly { get; set; }
  public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
  public bool IsVerified { get; set; }
  public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
  public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Lyric> Lyrics { get; set; } = new List<Lyric>();
  public string UserId { get; set; }
  public BbUser User { get; set; }
}
```

I need a one-to-many relationship between `BbUser` and `Artist`. One user can submit many artists and lyrics ...etc. Simple stuff really.

**PROBLEM**

The application builds fine, but when I attempt to run it by hitting a controller that requires access to the Database, I get the following error:

> The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin' requires a primary key to be defined.

I had this issues with regular EF Code First (not Core) and [the fix for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28532180/613605), does not work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This model worked for me(compiled, and no exceptions at runtime) if I used next code in the DbContext class:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<BbUser>(b => b.ToTable("AspNetUsers"));
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
```

Without calling  `base.OnModelCreating(builder)` I get the same error, because in this case context isn't applying the Identity related schema.

**UPDATE**:
Everything works fine for me as you can see from the screenshot below:
[image]

I have one more idea why you can have such an error. Did your BbContext inherit from `DbContext` class or `IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>`? Because I got the same error that was on your screenshot if I used usual `DbContext` class.

In order to Idenity tables work fine you should use `IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>`. Below the whole code for my working DbContext class

```
 public class BbContext :IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
        public BbContext(DbContextOptions options):base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Lyric> Lyrics { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Heart> Hearts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<BbUser>(b => b.ToTable("AspNetUsers"));
            builder.Entity<Heart>().HasKey(h => new {h.UserId, h.LyricId});
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just went ahead and [tried what you suggested](https://www.screencast.com/t/xnwgQlAt4). Sadly I get the same error.

Comment: @Ciwan Strange, can you show the LINQ query which generate such an error?

Comment: I don't have a LINQ query as such. I just want to test to ensure my Db gets created, so I've created a [DummyController](https://gist.github.com/Ciwan1859/e9a2d6ddcee0c2145a2b3e434c4021af) passing in my context via the constructor. This should force the EF Core to create my Database, and as you can see, that error gets in the way of that.

Comment: @Ciwan I see, please check my updated answer, it worked fine for me using its solution.

Comment: I was using `DbContext`. I changed that for `IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>` and it all now works fine. Thank you v. much.

Answer (score 0):

Please do try declaring a Guid property named `Id`, with both Get and Set on the `IdentityUserLogin` entity.

Another option is to declare a property and decorate it with `[Key]` attribute