# How to merge DbContext with IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am attempting to get away from code-first migrations.

The problem is that AspNetUsers is extending IdentityUser. As a result, when I try to use a DbContext then I get the following errors.

- EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for
  this EntityType.
- EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

I want to use AspNetUsers for two purposes:

1. Identity management.
2. Querying users from the database.

Is it possible to go this route without having to use IdentityDbContext?

```
public class MyEntities : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531201/entitytype-identityuserlogin-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to add

```
public DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
```

inherit your context from IdentityDbContext to have only one context

```
public class MyEntities : IdentityDbContext<AspNetUsers>
```

also don't forget to set up UserManager to use your MyEntities context with AspNetUsers

Comment: That worked, thank you sir. I had already taken care of the MyEntities context with AspNetUsers. But, it was all relevant so I mark yours as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid using the IdentityDbContext but you need to setup the mapping yourself in the OnModelCreating method within your DbContext class.

However, if you are using the SignInManager etc.. I recommend you use the IdentityDbContext. You are not constraint to use Code-First Migrations.

Comment: I did not need to add anything to the OnModelCreating. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1):

Identity context inherits from DBContext. Hence as long as your own db context inherits from identity context, it should be enough. Something like following :-

```
public class MyDbContext : IdentityContext {}
```

Comment: This was also part of the answer, but Nikolay provided additional context that was necessary. I thank you for responding to this post.