# ModelState.isValid()==False + Required-notation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, modelstate

I am using Identity framework for my project and have added some properties such as `JobExperience` to the `User` class.

A user should have the possibility of adding a `JobExperience` to their `User`. Naturally, that means that a `JobExperience` shouldn't be able to exist without the `User`.

For that reason I am using the [Required]-notation in my `JobExperience`class

**JobExperience class**

```
public class JobExperience
{
    public int JobExperienceId { get; set; }
    public string Employer { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfEmployment { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfExit { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual User ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

**User class**

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public Boolean Available { get; set; }
    public Boolean ActivelySeeking { get; set; }
    public Boolean AcceptedUseOfData { get; set; }
    public int ExpectedHourlySalary { get; set;}
    public Boolean Gender { get; set;}
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<JobExperience> JobExperiences { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Language> Languages { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Certificate> Certificates { get; set; }
}
```

**Scaffolded JobExperienceController** - Create method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "JobExperienceId,Employer,DateOfEmployment,DateOfExit")] JobExperience jobExperience)
{
    var UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    jobExperience.ApplicationUser = db.Users.Where(x => x.Id == UserId).First();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       db.JobExperiences.Add(jobExperience);
       db.SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(jobExperience);
}
```

After having added the Required-notation the modelstate.isValid() in the create method returns false. I'm guessing it needs to receive a reference to the User but I have no idea how to go about it. The current attempt is the LINQ-expression shown.

**ApplicationUserDb**

```
 public class ApplicationUserDb : IdentityDbContext<User>
{

    public virtual DbSet<JobExperience> JobExperiences { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Certificate> Certificates { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUserDb() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    internal static ApplicationUserDb Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationUserDb();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to model the relationship between `User` <-> `JobExperience` as 1 (required) <-> 0-N (optional list). You will not achieve this by marking the ApplicationUser as `[Required]`. Instead, configure the multiplicity constraints in the `ModelBuilder` and remove the `[Required]` attribute.

```
ModelBuilder.Entity<User>()
   .HasMany(u => u.JobExperiences)
   .WithRequired(j => j.ApplicationUser)
   .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Tutorial: [Configure One-to-Many Relationships in EF 6](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx).

As a further note, you should introduce ViewModels instead of binding your Entity Models to the controller. This way you will not mix annotations that are used for frontend validation (e.g. `[Required]`) and annotations that are used for data persistance (e.g. `[ForeignKey]`).

If `User` inherits from `IdentityUser`, also make sure to call the `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)` in your ModelBuilder (see [EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34786782/1450855)
).

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer was close to solving all of the issues. After implementing your solution i got an error saying; "EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType". I found out that the answer to that problem could be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531201/entitytype-identityuserlogin-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entit

(SEE 2ND ANSWER ON QUESTION)

I would love to mark your answer as the solution! Maybe you could refer to this message in your answer, then i'll accept it :)

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)

Comment: It is very much appreciated, I was stuck on this for more than a day!
Please read my message i just sent, I want to mark your answer as accepted, but I think if you could add what i found to your answer, it might help more people.